# Any way to test that a method starts pry?

Tags: ruby, rspec, pry

I'm building a gem that allows for a much more convenient and configurable 'console' for ruby gem development than the current options (ie: 'bundle console').

As such, one of if not the most important aspects of the entire gem is that it does in fact open a console session, which I currently have set up in a start method:

```
class MyConsole 
  def start
    Pry.start(self)
  end
end
```

I am trying to test this functionality, but it's difficult because their's not a lot of good resources for this. It's also really annoying because every time I run this method in rspec, pry opens, and I have to exit it before finishing the rest of the tests.

I have three main questions:

1. How can I run a method in rspec that starts pry without actually starting pry?
2. How can I specifically test that that method does in fact start pry?
3. Assuming 1 and 2 are possible, how can I test what context the method starts pry in? (notice how the start method calls Pry.start(self), meaning the pry session should open in the context of a MyConsole instance.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would probably be using an RSpec [spy](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/basics/spies).

Your test would probably look something like this:

```
describe MyConsole do
  describe '#start' do
    it 'calls Pry.start' do
      described_class.start
      expect(Pry).to have_received(:start).with('your_args_here')
    end
  end
end
```

This is a really good explanation of RSpec stubbing options, IMO, where you can learn more: https://about.futurelearn.com/blog/stubs-mocks-spies-rspec

Comment: I was able to get this working with a couple small tweaks, 1) I had to move the line ```described_class.start``` to below the expectation, and 2) I had to use 'receive' instead of 'have_received' ```expect(Pry).to receive(:start).with('your_args_here')```

Comment: Once I did that though it passed all three rules I laid out! If you make the changes I mentioned I'll mark this correct.